# Open and Save As Dialog position

Tags: windows, winapi

Hi I use Visual Studio 2010. I use OPENFILENAME structure and functions GetSaveFileName GetOpenFileName to show Save As (Open) dialogue. The problem is that first time it is launched it appears in the top-left (0,0) of the screen. That looks really bad and user has always a tendency to move the window in the middle of the screen before working with it. No I have looked sort of everywhere to solve this problem and haven't finde any final answer. I have set the owner of the window and it didn't help. I have also tried hooking it set the window Position in the hookProcedure. But that (for some strange) reason always changes the dialogue style and also it works only for the first time. Next time the window is shown the dialogue alligns with top left of the parrent window. I just don't get it.

I have also tried to use the new IFileOpenDialog, and IFileSaveDialog but it didn't compile (I use Windows 7) - undefined indentifiers. Do I need to include something other than windows.h?

And one last thing... I need the program to ran correctly in XP as well (IFileDialogue was introduced with Vista and I don't really understand whether it is backwards compatible).

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have also tried to create an invisible window in the middle of the screen and set this as an owner of the Open/Save As dialog... It does not help. The window is still in the top left of the main window in XP. In Win7 I don't know, because it always remebers the last position even if I restart the application.